# bootstrap datepicker can't set minDate

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I made a lot of modification, i tried a lot of differents things, but nothing works. I have a isabled field in which a date is contained (25-05-2016). I would like to set a minDate to my datepicker with this value (25-05-2016).
Nothing works, even if i set the value directly. Here is my code:

```
var myDate = $('#CRUEventModal #rdvStartDate').val(); //Get the value from field
myDate = moment(myDate , "DD-MM-YYYY");
//myDate  = moment(myDate , "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'months'); one of things i tried

var myDate2 = $('#CRUEventModal #rdvStartDate').val(); // Another things i tried
myDate2 = moment(myDate2 , "DD-MM-YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');

$('#rdvFinDatefinPicker')
    .datepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        language:"fr",
        autoclose:"true",
        minDate: myDate  //myDate2 didn't work too!
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date field
        //$('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'eventDate');
    });
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which component are you using? Can you link it?

Comment: i realise i used this: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but i rode the doc of this: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ 
Finally i changed all files to use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
i made a mix, sorry! when you google "bootstrap datepicker" you find a lot of libraries!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#rdvFinDatefinPicker')
        .datepicker({
            useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            **startDate: '28-05-2016',**
            language:"fr",
            autoclose:"true",

        })
```

You should use startdate function which is date start you want or enddate function also helpful for maxdate...thnaks

Comment: Thank, actually i juste realise that i did not read the good documentation. Your answer is based on this: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0-rc.4/options.html#startdate
My question was based on this: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and in my code, i used the first link. Finally i don't know which library is the best. Any advices?

Comment: Yea. I am also use this bootstrap 3 from date and time picker. but after its problem to startdate and enddate.. after I update this bootstrap and i found same functionality as datepicker... I was do in this bootstrap aslo but now i dont know how to do it.. if i find it.. i will update you..

Answer (score 0):

Using [eonasdan datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) you can have the following code:

```js
var myDate = $('#rdvStartDate').val(); //Get the value from field
myDate = moment(myDate , "DD-MM-YYYY");

$('#rdvFinDatefinPicker')
    .datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        locale:"fr",
        minDate: myDate
    })
    .on('dp.change', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date field
        //$('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'eventDate');
    });
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input id="rdvStartDate" type='text' class="form-control" value="25-05-2016" disabled />
<div class='input-group date' id='rdvFinDatefinPicker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note that you have to import the french locale for momentjs and set the [`locale`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale) option. The format option has to follow [momentjs rules](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), so you have to specify it uppercase. You don't need the `autoclose` option since the datetimepicker has a [`keepOpen`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepopen) option that is `false` by default.

Note that the datetimepicker fires [`dp.change` event](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange).

I prefer eonasdan datetimepicker because it uses momentjs and it has a rich API.

Answer (score 0):

```
**$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
           // format: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a',
            format: "dd-M-yyyy, HH:ii P",
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+60m',
            showMeridian: true,
            autoclose: true
        });
```

otherwise

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
       format: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a',
       useCurrent: false,
       minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(),

       locale: 'de',

     });
   });
```

in mindate add as your day you want to start.. I hope that it will be use it
first code I am using in my project...it was working well,.